# web2py webserver - Best way to keep connection to external SQL server?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, database-connection, web2py

I have a simple web2py server that we use to visualize data from our PostgreSQL Server. The following functions are all part of the global models in web2py.

The current solution to fetch data is very simple. Every time I connect, and after I get the data I close the connection:

```
# Old way:
# (imports excluded)  
def get_data(query):
    postgres_connection = psycopg2.connect("credentials")
    df = psql.frame_query(query, con=postgres_connection) # Pandas function to put data from query into DataFrame
    postgres.close()
    return df
```

For small queries, opening and closing the connection takes about 9/10 of the time run the function.

Is this a good way to do it instead? If not, what is a better way?

```
# Better way?
def connect():
    """
    Create a connection to server.
    """
    return psycopg2.connect("credentials")

db_connection = connect()

def create_pandas_frame(query):
    """
    Get query if connection is open.
    """
    return psql.frame_query(query, con=db_connection)    

def get_data(query):
    """
    Try to get data, open a new conneciton if connection is closed.
    """
    try:
        data = create_pandas_frame(query)
    except:
        global db_connection
        db_connection = connect()
        data = create_pandas_frame(query)
    return data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run that code in a web2py model file, you'll end up creating a new connection on each HTTP request anyway. Instead, you might consider [connection pooling](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html).

An easier option might be to use the web2py DAL to fetch the data. Something like:

```
from pandas.core.api import DataFrame
db = DAL([db connection string], pool_size=10, migrate_enabled=False)
rows = db.executesql(query)
data = DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=[list, of, column, names])
```

If you specify the [`pool_size`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Connection-pooling) argument to `DAL()`, it will automatically maintain a connection pool to be used across requests.

Note, I haven't tried this, so it may need some tweaking, but something along these lines should work.

If you'd like, you can even use the DAL to generate the SQL by defining database table models:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('field1', 'integer'),
    Field('field2', 'double'),
    Field('field3', 'boolean'))

rows = db.executesql(db(db.mytable.id > 0)._select())
data = DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=db.mytable.fields)
```

The `._select()` method just generates the SQL without actually doing the select. The SQL is then passed to `.executesql()` to fetch the data.

An alternative is to create a special Pandas processor and pass it as the `processor` argument to `.select()`.

```
def pandas_processor(rows, fields, columns, cacheable):
    return DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=columns)

data = db(db.mytable.id > 0).select(processor=pandas_processor)
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I should have read the DAL chapter more closely. The reason I have not used it so much is that I know the support for Postgres Schamas is not yet the best.

The first suggestion worked out fine. Passing the as_dict command to the executesql function will return a structure that is very easy to use with Pandas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used Anthony's answer and now have functions that look like this:

```
# In one of the models files.
from pandas.core.api import DataFrame
external_db = DAL('postgres://connection_stuff',pool_size=10,migrate_enabled=False)
def create_simple_html_table(query):
    dict_from_db = external_db.executesql(query, as_dict=True)
    return DataFrame(dict_from_db).to_html()
```

Then later in a view or controller a html table is created using:

```
# In Controller:
my_table = create_simple_html_table('select * from random_table limit 50')
# In View:
{{=XML(create_simple_html_table('select * from random_table limit 50'))}}
```

I still need to do more testing, but my understanding so far is that this solution will let me query things from the external db and let web2py keep the connection, and let web2py use the same connection for all users.

Note that this solution is only good if all you want to do is to read and write to you Postgres server with raw SQL.

If you want to use DAL to read and write, you need to either try to find the DAL alternative called MyDAL or play around with the search_path option in Postgres.

Comment: If you need to use a Postgres schema, just do `db.executesql('set search_path to myschema')` before running your queries. I think you can even do: `db = DAL(..., after_connection=lambda self: self.execute('set search_path to myschema'))`. That will set the search path when the db connection is made.

Comment: Also, note that if you just want HTML tables of the data, if you use the `DAL` to select the data, you can then use `SQLTABLE` or `SQLFORM.grid` to generate nice HTML tables.

Comment: Thank you, I am using pandas for many other things such as plotting and data manipulation. But perhaps it is time to start exploring the DAL more.